# change default mysql storage engine on Ubuntu

Tags: mysql

I've installed mysql 5.1.49 on Ubuntu. I've added the following line to the end of `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
default-storage-engine=innodb
```

I've restarted the `mysqld` process, then run

```
mysql> show engines;
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine     | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB     | YES     | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| MRG_MYISAM | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE  | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| CSV        | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY     | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED  | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
| ARCHIVE    | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM     | DEFAULT | Default engine as of MySQL 3.23 with great performance         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
+------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
```

As you can see MyISAM is still the default, what am I missing? I've also run

```
sudo find / -name 'my.cnf'
```

to verify that there is no other `my.cnf` file present on the system

Comment: Erm...  I'm confused. You edited the `my.cnf` but also confirmed that there's no `my.cnf` on your system?  Did it disappear?

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, fixed it now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably in the wrong section of the my.cnf file.

You need to set that variable in the `[mysqld]` section. If you put it at the end of the config file, it's probably in a different section, since `[mysqld]` is typically the first section, not the last.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have put `default-storage-engine=innodb` in the appropriate `[group]`, usually `[mysqld]`.